# How Can I get a bit-perfect copy of a CF card?

Tags: iso-image, fat32, compact-flash

Is there any way I can get a bit level copy of a Fat32 compact flash card? Like make an ISO of it or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boot up using a linux live cd like [PLD Rescue](http://rescuecd.pld-linux.org/) and use [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) to make a bitwise copy.

Comment: What command does dd need to do the copy as an iso or similar file?

Comment: OOps.. nevermind. Found the answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning